# Django Template Message Resolution

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and I want to know the best practice for resolving messages from data in django templates.
My model has various tokens in it that need to be replaced with user-friendly messages.
like:

```
MyModelObject.MyProperty = 'FOO'
```

becasue that's what's stored in the db, but in the template, I can't just output

```
{{ MyModelObject.MyProperty }}
```

which is 'FOO'.  I may want to output something like "This value is Foo." Or any string for which 'FOO' would be a key.
Is there a way to declare a dictionary in a template, or another supported framework construct?

I'd rather not code a long list of conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a dictionary in your view that maps internal return values to user-friendly messages. pass this dict to your template. Alternatively you may want to investigate the django messaging framework - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: yeah it mixes presentation and logic... I'm like to keep my code clean but there's no point in being anal... In a simple case like this you can get away with it. Once your dict starts getting too big or you start needing to add extra logic to e.g. deal with singular/plural in your error messages it is definately time to move the logic into your views. But as long as it's simple... Anyway use of the messaging framework would be better if your worried about mixing logic/presentation. Or write a template tag if you need more sophisticated behaviour. Oh and please accept my answer if you use it.